# Keyboard shortcuts for Zeppelin Notebook

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, apache-zeppelin

There was an old jira for keyboard shortcuts. But there did not appear to be an associated document

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-391

Is there a comprehensive cheat-sheet for the shortcuts?  Especially to compare to the excellent `jupyter` keyboard shortcuts; e.g. dd to delete a cell.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is a table for the shortcuts.

```
| shortcut          | meaning                           |
|-------------------|-----------------------------------|
| Ctrl + up         | move focus to previous paragraph  |
| Ctrl + down       | move focus to next paragraph      |
| Shift + Enter     | run the current paragraph         |
| Ctrl + Alt + c    | cancel paragraph                  |
| Ctrl + Alt + d    | remove paragraph                  |
| Ctrl + Alt + k    | move up                           |
| Ctrl + Alt + j    | move down                         |
| Ctrl + Alt + a    | insert new above                  |
| Ctrl + Alt + b    | insert new below                  |
| Ctrl + Alt + o    | toggle output                     |
| Ctrl + Alt + r    | toggle enable/disable             |
| Ctrl + Alt + e    | toggle editor                     |
| Ctrl + Alt + m    | toggle showing line numbers       |
| Ctrl + Shift + -  | width - 1                         |
| Ctrl + Shift + =  | width + 1                         |
| Ctrl + Alt + t    | toggle title                      |
```

> Note: Some shortcut might not work depend on OS and browser.

Comment: Thanks.  Zeppelin is not working and nothing in the logs - so I can't verify these. Will take "on faith" for now .. and until I have time again to deal with this poorly documented and poor usability  software.

Comment: Are these the same for Mac?

Answer (score 12):

There is a keyboard icon that lists them:
[image]

It is is missing some e.g.

```
ctrl + /         comment whole line
ctrl + shift + / in-line comment
```

Comment: How to recover a deleted paragraph or cell?